# Find minimal set of rows to retain all unique values in each column

Tags: fastest-code

Given a matrix, the goal is to ensure all the values in each column occur at least once, while at the same time doing so requiring the least possible amount of rows. Fastest solution wins.

Note: a value in one column (e.g. 1) is considered different from the same value in another column.

Expected output: an array/list/series of row indices that retain all unique values across all columns.

**Example data:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)

num_rows = 10000
num_cols = 200
max_uniq_values = 10

data = pd.DataFrame({i: np.random.randint(0, max_uniq_values, num_rows)
                     for i in range(num_cols)})
# or python
# data = [np.random.randint(0, max_uniq_values, num_rows).tolist()
#         for i in range(num_cols)]
```

**Minimal example (num_rows=5, num_cols=2, max_uniq_values=4)**

Input:

```
    | 0  1
  --------
  0 | 1  1
  1 | 2  2
  2 | 3  4
  3 | 3  3
  4 | 4  4
```

Expected output:

```
[0, 1, 3, 4]
```

**Additionally**:

- Benchmark will happen on a 2015 Macbook Pro with CPU Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz.
- Restricted to use 1 core.
- External libraries allowed
- Blind test will be done on 10 random seeds (the same ones for each solution)

Comment: Wow, ok, your question is poorly worded. You want to *`SELECT`* the least number of rows to have unique values in each row for all columns. I definitely did not get that from your Question.

Comment: Your example is really confusing because you're saying 2 columns, but the example contains 3 columns. Please don't copy/paste from Pandas and consider re-writing the question using pure Python.

Comment: Your own question states "all the values **in each column** occur..." If all columns don't matter, then this statement is wrong.

Comment: @mmla The "first" column is the row index. It's not part of the data set. Which is why there's a blank spot on the first row/first column area.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, I know. It adds nothing to the problem statement. Why include it?

Comment: @Draco18s @mmla I now show it more as a table structure. The idea is that the index is still useful to refer to the indices as in the `Output` - but I understand at first glance it was confusing.

Comment: Your "python" way to get example data has interchanged rows and columns. And you seem much too optimistic wrt the order of magnitude of the sizes a program that finds the optimal solution can handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Python3 + [PuLP](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp) library

This is equivalent to a set covering problem (where the elements are column/value pairs) which can be transformed into an integer linear programming problem.

```
from pulp import *

def opt(mat):
    num_rows = len(mat)
    covering_rows = {}
    for row_nr, vals in enumerate(mat):
        for pair in enumerate(vals):
            covering_rows.setdefault(pair, []).append(row_nr)
    prob = LpProblem("Minimal Covering Set of Rows", LpMinimize)
    vars = LpVariable.dicts("R", range(num_rows), 0, 1, LpInteger)
    prob += lpSum([vars[i] for i in range(num_rows)])
    for rowlist in covering_rows.values():
        prob += lpSum([vars[r] for r in rowlist]) >= 1
    prob.solve()
    assert prob.status==LpStatusOptimal, "Couldn't solve"
    return [r for r in range(num_rows) if value(vars[r])==1]
```

On debian, the relevant package is called `python3-pulp`.

The function handles matrices with 20 columns and 100 rows in about one minute on weak hardware. The best way to substantially improve the speed is probably to use a better solver, which the PuLP library allows by adding an argument to the `solve` method call.

Comment: I am not sure what transformation is expected from the DataFrame example to be taken as input for opt?

Comment: @PascalVKooten The function takes an ordinary list of lists, so the small example is computed like this: `opt([[1,1],[2,2],[3,4],[3,3],[4,4]])`.

Comment: Thanks! It is very slow but it is a solution that gets an optimal result. The alternative of doing a greedy solution is much faster, but at the cost of not giving an optimal solution.

Comment: I was not able to find an optimizer that gave me a faster solution than 1 minute.

Comment: You asked for a minimal set, not a small one. I don't think you can do that much faster. Asking for the best solution one can get in a fixed time would have been another interesting challenge. What input sizes did you use in your tests?

Comment: Indeed, which is why your solution is the best as it stands. It's more for anyone who reads this to reconsider if a small set is good enough. I used your 100 by 20 to take 1 minute for an actual minimal set. As for a greedy solution, it was possible to do 10k by 200 in under a second. Further details: the minimal solution would yield 18 rows, the greedy one would yield 21 (on the 100 rows).